# Why i cant struct variable S be used to access members

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C right now, and I have some basic struct questions. I want to clear up:

```
#define MaxSize 1024
#define ElementType int
struct DStack
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    int Top1; // Stack top 1
    int Top2; // the top 2
} S, S2;

S.Top1 = -1;
S.Top2 = MaxSize;
```

An error occurred when i compiled the code.

```
doubleStack.c:17:2: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
   17 | S.Top1 = -1;
      |  ^
doubleStack.c:18:2: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
   18 | S.Top2 = MaxSize;
```

My compiler is `gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

My compiled command is `gcc doubleStack.c -o dbs && .\dbs`

I cant find what's wrong with my code.

In my Knowledge system, struct can be used like this:

```c
struct stu{
    int num;  
    int age;  
};
// or
struct stu{
    int num;  
    int age;  
}stu1, stu2;
```

I hope you can help me find out the my mistakes.

Thx in advance.

Comment: you have to assign variable inside function or after declaring variable in global section.

Comment: You can't have assignments or general statements outside of functions. Quite honestly, doesn't the book you read or tutorial you follow or class you take mention this anywhere?

Comment: In the future, when entering questions, use compiler messages taken directly from the code you post. The messages you pasted into the question show line numbers of 17 and 18, but there are only 11 lines of code, so we know you got the messages trying to compile some other source file and pasted only part of the source code into the question. In more complicated problems, the different line numbers make it harder to figure out where the error is. Once you have selected the lines to paste into the question, you should put them in a separate file, compile that, and paste the resulting messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do assignment (`s.Top1 = -1;`) outside a function.

You can:

```
#define MaxSize 1024
#define ElementType int
struct DStack
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    int Top1; // Stack top 1
    int Top2; // the top 2
} S, S2;

int main(void) {
  S.Top1 = -1;
  S.Top2 = MaxSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have statements such as `S.Top1 = -1;` outside of functions, but you can specify the initial values of variables defined out of functions, using an *initializer*.

For your example:

```
#define MaxSize 1024
#define ElementType int
struct DStack
{
    ElementType Data[MaxSize];
    int Top1; // Stack top 1
    int Top2; // the top 2
};

struct DStack S = {
    .Top1 = -1,
    .Top2 = MaxSize
};
struct DStack S2;
```

The above initialization of `S` uses the *designated initializer* syntax that allows the initial values to be specified for individual members or array elements. Unspecified members and array elements will be initialized to 0.

Designated initializers have been a standard feature since the 1999 version of the C standard but some older compilers do not support them. If designated initializers are not supported, `S` can be initialized using the older form of initializer syntax as follows:

```
struct DStack S = {
    {0},    /* Data[] */
    -1,     /* Top1 */
    MaxSize /* Top2 */
};
```

Using the older syntax, values in the initializer are used to initialize members in the same order they are declared within the `struct`, or used to initialize array elements starting at index 0 onwards.  Nested `{` `}` within the initializer can be used to initialize compound objects contained within another object as has been done to initialize the `Data` array member above. If the nested `{` `}` was not used, it would be necessary to have 1024 initial values for `Data` followed by the initial values for `Top1` and `Top2`. The use of `{0}` above specifies that `Data[0]` is initialized to 0 explicitly and the remaining elements of `Data` (`[1]` thru `[1023]`) will be initialized to the default value 0 implicitly.